# Authors who think Capitalism encourage psychopathic behaviour?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, economics

When morality and ethics is a problem to a great deal of people is it safe to assume that capitalism rewards those individuals with no empathy or remorse who are good at emulating to have them?

> e.g. Stock brokers who invest in corporations who pollute the
>   environment, sell weapons to terrorists or invest in medical companies
>   who won't research any cure to diseases because they are making large
>   profits out them.

I'm looking for authors and books against or in favour of this idea.

[Reference here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_leadership)

Comment: This question is more about psychology not philosophy. Here's a relevant article: https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/sep/29/neoliberalism-economic-system-ethics-personality-psychopathicsthic

Comment: On second thought, this question be reformulated to have significant philosophical content - if you try to place it within a specific ethics framework.

Comment: If the question needs to be reformulated it's because this is not a real philosophy forum. OK case closed.

Comment: The question reminded of a book that I read some time ago, [The Corporation: The pathological pursuit of profit & power](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Corporation-Pathological-Pursuit-Profit-Power/dp/1845291743/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1487885051&sr=8-1&keywords=the+corporation), you might find it interesting reading.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing So this is "opinion-based" and "Should I respect other people's religions?" is not. In fact it is "protected by the community". We should have a debate on how medals and points (ego) affect people clarity of thinking, bias judgement, and freedom of speech but not in this network of course...

Comment: @MoziburUllah I expected conclusions based on books like that just like the reference I posted but you know how this networks work. If somebody with 3000+ don't like what you are asking they close your questions....

Comment: @pbxman: I think it might be because it causes some discomfort & unease - after all this platform is run by a company after all! Or perhaps it just means we get into discussion flame-wars; but this is why the site promotes discussion around texts; it doesn't help, I agree, when there are people around who press their own agenda without due consideration.

Comment: @MoziburUllah philosophy is not a programming language, ideas are meant to be expressed and discussed. Nothing wrong with liking good answers but closing a question is censorship. In other words and sick and tired of this shit network. "I do not agree with what you say but I'll defend to the death your right to say it" Voltaire

Comment: Anyway I've voted to re-open; I'd answer it myself, but it's been ten years since I read that text and it intrigued me because it was taking a different slant to economics by looking at business or institutional psychology; I think it has an interesting overlap with behavioral economics; actually, even Adam Smith was interested in this - he wrote *A Theory of Moral Sentiments*, it's on my shelf but I haven't read it - it's an inch think; it would be strange though if he didn't discuss economics within that framework; I have read certain statements by people I respect that he did.

Comment: @PbxMan (a) I personally flagged as a psychology question not a philosophy question. Others flagged it as opinion based. (b) I am actually the only that provided relevant feedback and a useful link, I don't see why you are being antagonistic towards me. (c) The only people capable of closing a question directly are diamond moderators, otherwise it is a democratic process based on number of close votes. (d) I think you can turn this into a good question if you reframe it as an ethics question, and for what it' worth I am sympathetic to the idea that capitalism does indeed encourage psychos.

Comment: I'd agree there is a certain authoritarian/fascistic streak involved - without naming any names; you should look at Plato and his description of how pure democracies tend to this and why he disparaged them; this is why most democracies aren't pure, they're a mixture; this might help in theorising the network effect that you've experienced.

Comment: Yeah, and definitely 'philosophy isn't a programming language'!

Comment: @AlexanderSKing that's exactly my point. This network is not suitable for philosophy btw was Marx a psychologist? Ethics and Economy have never been discussed in philosophy? I have the feeling that If I made this question in a psychology SE.forum they would send me back here or perhaps they would close it as "Too broad". BTW I'm sick and tired of arguing about this issue and I sound like a troll, this is my last comment. Good luck ego-censored-shit channel.

Comment: lets discuss this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=philosophy.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Francis Fukayama just came up in another context.  He represents a thread that would say no.  He does admit this is true of our system currently, but he suggests that is not intrinsic to capitalism, it is  because other real capital -- environmental wealth and social structure are not expressed as capital, even though when they are degraded, they create 'interest' on the resulting debt, in the form of excessive maintenance and corruption.  Sorry to give an answer in a comment, but I did not make it back here before the question closed.

Comment: Capitalism doesn't encourage bad behaviour, see "The Virtue of Seflishness" and "Atlas Shrugged" by Ayn Rand.

Comment: @alanf that would be a valid answer to me. it's a Pitty that this question is closed.

Comment: The Psychopath Teat (2011) Jon Ronson discuss both the affirmative concept and the subjectiveness of attempting such an analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By way of a solution to the undoubted problems of capitalism, an amusing article for the recoding of capitalism has appeared on Wikipedia.  Really just along the lines of corporate social responsibility, with full holistic considerations.

Wiki - [Criticism of Criticisms of Capitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_capitalism#Criticism_of_criticisms_of_capitalism)

Note 116 - selected quotes from the PDF

> Only few disagree that the one-dimensional growth obsession of
>   capitalist societies is a global threat. The general view is that
>   there are reasonable limits to growth that, once exceeded, indicate a
>   need for degrowth. ...
>
> A repoliticization of growth therefore could be a valid strategy to
>   achieve the overall goals of the degrowth movement. ...
>
> Our routine hence turns organizational function system biases from
>   implicit constants into explicit variables. This switch enables
>   economically biased organizations to code more decisions in the
>   languages of non-economic function systems. ...
>
> Organizations for and of a postgrowth economy will hence be less
>   concerned with questions economic de-/growth and more with a growing
>   interest for de-/growth in other function systems of society.

Answer (score -1):

I think that purely out of a business approach what you say is not true. Corporate Citizenship has if not proven greatly emphasised the importance of companies being pillars of the community.

The manner in which a business is thought of in the community has great impact unto its success. If capatilism has any impact on morality I would think it would be to the good. As long as the management had enough vision.

Comment: I don't normally down-vote; but this answer is purely opinion...